# Is it possible to access specific item of Counter without using for loop?

Tags: python, counter

Is it possible to access specific item of Counter?

```
from collections import Counter
s=['a','b','r','e', 'a', 'r','r']
print(Counter(s))
```

Output

```
Counter({'r': 3, 'a': 2, 'b': 1, 'e': 1})
```

I want to access `('a':2)` or for example `('a': 2, 'b': 1)` items, how to do it without using for loop?

I couldn't access `('a':2)` using `print(Counter(s).items([1]))`.

---

My answer:

```
s=sorted(['a','e','r','b', 'a', 'r','r'])

x=Counter(s)
y={k: v for k, v in sorted(x.items(), key=lambda item: item[1], reverse=True)}

i=0
for key,value in y.items():
    if i<3:
        print(str(key) + " " + str(value))
        i+=1
```

I sorted the list in the beginning so that if the values of the items are equal, then the alphabetic order will be preserved.

Comment: The Counter returns in dictionary format and an element can be accessed by it key...

Comment: TLDR: `counter.get("a")`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I sort a dictionary by value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/613183/how-do-i-sort-a-dictionary-by-value)

Comment: step 1: get the dict: `counter.items()`. step 2: use the link to sort dict by values ...

Comment: `Counter` is a subclass of `dict`; `Counter(s)` *is* a `dict`, just with extra methods.

Answer (score 1):

`Counter` has a `most_common` method that returns a list of key-value pairs in decreasing order of their count.

```
>>> s = ['a','b','r','e', 'a', 'r','r']
>>> Counter(s).most_common(3)
[('r', 3), ('a', 2), ('b', 1)]
```

Comment: if you change 'b' and 'e' inside list s, then your code prints [('r', 3), ('a', 2), ('e', 1)], but since both b and e have same value, I want to print b, since it is first in alphabetic order

Comment: Would sorting the input first be sufficient? `Counter(sorted(s)).most_common(3)`. `Counter` is breaking ties based on which key was added first, not necessarily which values are lexicographically smaller.

Comment: I did exactly the same thing and yes it works, I have added my new answer to the question. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this?

```py
>>> c = Counter(s)
>>> find = 'a'
>>> (find, c[find])
('a', 2)
```

Comment: this is more of a comment rather than an answer ...

Comment: problem is that I don't know exactly what is the second item. For example some problems want me to print first 3 items, 1 item per line. OR print second and third item

Comment: maybe this will help you: `for letter, num_occurrences in counter.items(): ...`

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
import json
from collections import Counter
counter = Counter(['a','b','r','e', 'a', 'r','r'])
sorted_data = {
    letter: occurrences
    for letter, occurrences in sorted(
        counter.items(),
        key=lambda item: item[1],
        reverse=True
    )
}
print(json.dumps(sorted_data, indent=4))
```

Comment: Or, just sort the input to `Counter`, then dump `dict(counter.most_common())`.

Comment: if you change 'b' and 'e' inside list s, then your code prints [('r', 3), ('a', 2), ('e', 1), ('b',1)], but since both b and e have same value, I want to print b first, since it is first in alphabetic order